# #define with multiple values - C

Tags: c, strstr

newbie question :)

How can I define multiple value i.e.:

```
#define TEST_STRING "AA" || "BB"
```

The main code should be similar to this:

```
if ((strstr(STRING2COMPARE, TEST_STRING) != NULL)) {
    doSomething();}
```

Probably there is a better way.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Write a function that takes an array of `char *`.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You want to check if `STRING2COMPARE` contains the string `"AA"` or contains `"BB"` you need to run `strstr` twice. Ot just write your own function which takes an array of strings to compare and OR-es the comparatison results.

Comment: Macros are nothing more than text substitutions - they have no "smarts" to them.  If you need to test against multiple strings, then you need to test against each string individually.

Comment: Any way that works would be _"a better way"_.  Macros are simple text replacements not C code.  Your suggestion resolves to `strstr( STRING2COMPARE, "AA" || "BB" )` which is not valid C code.  This looks like an X-Y problem - you are asking how to implement an implausible solution to some unknown problem - better to just ask us about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Mmh first I think your idea was to get in TEST_STRING the concatenation of the two strings.
In C, It would be (concatenation is implicit) :

```
#define TEST_STRING ("AA" "BB")
```

Second this test will succeed in a lot of cases where it must not : "A" "B" or "ABB" for instance.

Third, the capital letters of STRING2COMPARE often means it is a define. You want to use normal variable don't you ?

In conclusion, what about this implementation ?

```
#define TEST_STRING_1 "AA"
#define TEST_STRING_2 "BB"

if ( strcmp(str2compare, TEST_STRING_1) == 0
     || strcmp(str2compare, TEST_STRING_2) == 0 ) {
    doSomething();
}
```